# Set CSS -moz-transition with JS

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, styles

I'm making a webapp and I'm using CSS3 to make a div transform but I'm with a big problem with Firefox. I can make the Chrome, Opera and IE working but firefox not. To set the working browsers I use:

```
obj.style.WebkitTransform = "translateX(17%)";
obj.style.MozTransform= "translateX(17%)"; //edited
obj.style.msTransform = "translateX(17%)";
obj.style.transform= "translateX(17%)"; //edited
```

I've tried jQuery $("#content").css( "-moz-transform", "translateX(17%)" );  and a lot of things I found on the Internet and nothing.
Any sugestion?

EDIT:
In context, this is the original function:

```
    function mousewheelEvt(obj) {

    if (window.addEventListener)
        window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', wheel, false);
    window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = wheel;

    var slide=0;

    function wheel(event) {
        var delta = 0;
        if (!event) event = window.event;
        if (event.wheelDelta) {
            delta = event.wheelDelta;
            if (window.opera) delta = -delta;
        }
        if (delta)
        {

            if (delta < 0 && slide<=0 && slide>-6)
                 {
                    slide--;
                    console.log(slide);
                obj.style.WebkitTransform = "translateX("+(17*slide/2)+"%)";
                obj.style.MozTransform = "translateX("+(17*slide/2)+"%)";
                obj.style.msTransform = "translateX("+(17*slide/2)+"%)";
                obj.style.transform = "translateX("+(17*slide/2)+"%)";
                 }

            else if (delta > 0 && slide<=-1 && slide>=-6)
                {
                    slide++;
                    console.log(slide);
                obj.style.WebkitTransform = "translateX("+(17*slide/2)+"%)";
                obj.style.MozTransform = "translateX("+(17*slide/2)+"%)";
                obj.style.msTransform = "translateX("+(17*slide/2)+"%)";
                obj.style.transform = "translateX("+(17*slide/2)+"%)";
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the log show? And is `obj` coming through as expected?

Comment: Just to make sure, is the code that does the `.style.transform` set being reached in Firefox?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you’re switching back and forth between “transition” and “transform”. Even in your question.

```
obj.style.WebkitTransform = "translateX(17%)";
obj.style.MozTransform = "translateX(17%)";
obj.style.msTransform = "translateX(17%)";
obj.style.transform = "translateX(17%)";
```

Comment: Yes, you're right. But continue not working. I've made this error trying a solution.

Comment: @PauloNeves: Can we have some context, then, please? Your HTML and the code that gets `obj`, for example?

Comment: Yes, see my first post please.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my problem is with the mousewheel function and not with the css. I've ralized it when start to work with swipes.